# $\int_x \int_y \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \,\partial y} F =F(x,y)$?

Tags: calculus

Is it true that $\displaystyle\int_x \int_y  \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \,\partial y} F =F(x,y)$?

In 1 dimension  it's true $\displaystyle\int_x \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}  =F(x)$

Is there a general setting when it's true? Is it true for differential forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int\int{\partial^{2}{\rm F}\pars{x,y} \over \partial y\partial x}\,\dd y\,\dd x
&=
\int\bracks{{\partial{\rm F}\pars{x,y} \over \partial x} + {\rm f}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
=
{\rm F}\pars{x,y} + {\rm h}\pars{y} + \mbox{C} + \int\fermi\pars{x}\,\dd x
\end{align}
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int\int{\partial^{2}{\rm F}\pars{x,y} \over \partial y\partial x}\,\dd y\,\dd x
=
{\rm F}\pars{x,y} + {\rm g}\pars{x} + {\rm h}\pars{y}}
$$
where ${\rm g}\pars{x}$ and ${\rm h}\pars{y}$ are 'arbitrary' functions.

Comment: When you evaluate
$$\int \frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}\,dx$$
shouldn't you instead get $F(x,y) + \color{green}{g(y)}$ and hence
$$\int\int\frac{\partial^2 F(x,y)}{\partial y\partial x}\,dy\,dx = F(x,y) + g(y) + h(x)$$
where $h(x)$ represents the antiderivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: @ChristopherToni Yes. You are right. I already changed the result. Thanks.